# Crystal structures of heaviest nuclides' compounds

Tags: analytical-chemistry, crystal-structure, elements, x-ray-diffraction

What is the heaviest element of the periodic table for which there is a compound whose crystal structure has been completely resolved by X-ray diffraction?

Answer (score 7):

Since there were no further suggestions, I decided to use the references from my comment in an answer, which, I believe, is element 99, einsteinium.

Both single crystal x-ray diffraction (SCXRD) and powder x-ray diffraction (PXRD) have certain sample requirements/limitations:

1. Mass/amount

   - PXRD: lower limit is in micrograms region, ideally at least a couple of milligrams of polycrystalline sample;
   - SCXRD: a single crystal of a size of fractions of a millimeter.
2. Time

   - PXRD: solid polycrystalline sample must be homogeneous which sometimes requires prolonged synthesis time (minutes, hours) due to diffusion barrier (solid-solid, solid-liquid or solid-gas). A measurement itself on average only takes minutes;
   - SCXRD: in addition to the synthesis, growing a suitable single crystal for analysis normally takes days, maybe hours if you are lucky. A measurement itself on average takes hours, sometimes days.

Looking both at the end of periodic table of elements and these two constrains, I suspect it is unlikely that current techniques can be applied for *transfermium elements* and *fermium* itself as we neither have the necessary amounts nor time.

Among transuranium elements with $Z < 100$ plutonium $\ce{_{94}Pu}$ compounds appear to be of the greatest interest and probably the greatest number of published structures, too.
However, [einsteinium $\ce{_{99}Es}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einsteinium) exists as several relatively stable isotopes with half-lives of the magnitude of months and days and has a somewhat developed chemistry to speak of.

In 1968 Fujita et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10/bxzkjh)] having 3 μg of $\ce{^{253}Es}$ synthesized and reported crystal structures of einsteinium(III) chloride $\ce{EsCl3}$ and einsteinium(III) oxochloride $\ce{EsOCl},$ both determined via powder x-ray diffraction.
Reading the full text is encouraged, mainly to admire authors' ingenuity in overcoming technical difficulties (self-contamination of the isotope, film darkening by radiation, measurement of lattice parameters in temperature range from the room temperature to over 400 °C and so on) and overall concise writing style of the report.

$\ce{Es^3+}$ in both structures has C.N. 9 and coordinates in a single-capped square antiprism ligand environment:

[image: icsd-109002-EsCl3]

**Figure 1**. Crystal structure of $\ce{EsCl3}$ (ICSD-109002). Color code: $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$; $\color{#B31FD4}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Es}$.

[image: icsd-109003-EsOCl]

**Figure 2**. Crystal structure of $\ce{EsOCl}$ (ICSD-109003). Color code: $\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$; $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$; $\color{#B31FD4}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Es}$.

A few years later Haire and Baybarz [[2](https://doi.org/10/bbfgp4)] determined crystal structure of einsteinium(III) oxide $\ce{Es2O3}$ via electron diffraction, but this is another story.

#### References

1. Fujita, D. K.; Cunningham, B. B.; Parsons, T. C. Crystal Structures and Lattice Parameters of Einsteinium Trichloride and Einsteinium Oxychloride. *Inorganic and Nuclear Chemistry Letters* **1969**, 5 (4), 307–313. https://doi.org/10/bxzkjh. ([PDF](https://cloudfront.escholarship.org/dist/prd/content/qt7hz778j2/qt7hz778j2.pdf))
2. Haire, R. G.; Baybarz, R. D. Identification and Analysis of Einsteinium Sesquioxide by Electron Diffraction. *Journal of Inorganic and Nuclear Chemistry* **1973**, 35 (2), 489–496. https://doi.org/10/bbfgp4.